# JMenu#setEnabled(false) disables all actions instead of disabling the menu itself

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

According to a use case I am supposed to implement, the menu must be disabled at some point, so it should not be clickable at some point. It makes sense to simply set

```
JMenu menu = new JMenu();
menu.setEnabled(false);
```

And indeed it works in this code sample :

```
public class MenuTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(FrameTest::new);
    }
}

class FrameTest extends JFrame {

    public FrameTest() {
        super();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("test menu1");
        JMenu menu2 = new JMenu("test menu2");
        menuBar.add(menu1);
        menuBar.add(menu2);
        menu1.setEnabled(false);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

But in the code base I am working on this approach does not work,it leaves the menu enabled, but disables all encapsulated actions. Thats not what I am looking for. For certain reasons, mainly because its pretty large and wont fit here, I am not posting it, but the idea is the same. `JMenuBar` filled with `JMenu`'s which are filled with `AbstractActions`.
Are there is reasons why the results differ by using the same method `setEnabled(false)` on the class `JMenu`?

Comment: "For certain reasons, mainly because it pretty large and wont fit here, I am not posting it here ....". Always better to provide a [mcve]